# Standard recommendations and steps for writing introductory books

Tags: publications, writing, books

Suppose I plan to write an introduction to, say, statistics that's intended both for self-learning and as a companion to a university course.

Is there any standard advice about the following?

- Defining the scope of the book
- The planning of the writing process
- Organising the table of contents
- Models for organising the content of each section
- Maintaining coherence in the writing style across the book (especially when writing in co-authorship)
- How to write exercises/problems
- Models of interaction between content and exercises (and lessons)
- Any other topic related to the writing of a book like this

The answer should to be useful for introductory books for which these questions apply. However, the answer could use statistics or any other field as an example.

Comment: I think you are looking for a book or a course, not an answer that can be provided here. Too much to ask.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? There are lots of introductory statistics books available, at least in English, so the answer to your questions would depend on your motivation for writing another.

Comment: Thanks, @academic. I've chosen statistics just as an example. I was more interested in knowing what recommendations or models are there for an expert in a field who wants to write an introductory textbook. Maybe I should ask each (or some) of these questions separately?

Comment: @lfba My primary advice would be to teach a course in the subject, multiple times. Your textbook can start as notes which you distribute to the students, and refine it from there.

Comment: If you are an expert in any field then you should be able to define the scope, and structure the material in a logical progression to benefit the beginner - one of the advantages of being the “expert”...

Comment: @lfba  I'd be interested in the answers to some of your questions since I'm about halfway through what I hope will be Yet Another introductory textbook in my field.  I am particularly interested in the two questions relating to problems or exercises.  For your own purposes, however, the comment on teaching a course by academic and the comment by Solar Mike are bang on.

Comment: I remember the foreword to Engineering `Thermodynamics, Work and heat transfer by Rogers and Mayhew, where the authors thank current and past students for working with chapters as their notes, and also doing all the example and practice problems included in the book.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation (having done something like this) is to first teach one or more courses in this area for at least five years before writing your text.

Start off in year 1 by making slides or notes for your lectures using LaTeX. If you post those, you will have an incentive to get them right (and students will also find some errors). Fix the mistakes as you find them before year 2. After year 2, consider changing the organization or splitting up some material if students have more trouble with it.

After five or more years, you will have come up with a sensible organization of topics. You will know how to foreshadow and set the exposition up for later developments; will be familiar with common questions and misunderstandings; and, will have exercises already written (with answers).

Then write the book using your slides or lecture notes as a skeleton and incorporating the exercises you found helped students the most. (Don't forget to thank the students who found errors.) You can also add in topics you wanted to cover but previously did not.

As I mentioned, LaTeX is your friend for this. With the right organization, it can make your table of contents for you (as well as a table of figures and tables), create an index, and show a list of references with clickable URLs (if you create a PDF file).

After that, teach a couple of classes using the text and you will find areas to improve. You will also likely see tweaks to make your old slides/lecture notes fit the text better.

As for publishing, you can choose an academic press or self-publishing. Both stink.

An academic press will not do much editing, will probably re-type all of your hard work and introduce errors, will charge a high price that students may not want to pay, and will likely give you no revenue; however, they will distribute the book widely (often to libraries).

Self-publishing using a print-on-demand place will get you about the same amount of editing help, will earn you zero credibility, and will receive far less distribution. However, you may actually make a little bit of money, you will have much more control over pricing, and nobody will retype all your work and introduce errors.

I know people who have done both and most thought both options were not great but more seemed to be considering self-publishing because academic presses seem to offer so little for services now.